# Error: no se puede acceder a Jarfile

Tags: java, jar, weblogic

estoy tratando de instalar el WebLogic Server de Java y al intentar ejecutar el comando en el CMD me arroja el error que no puedo acceder al archivo .jar

Hice varios intentos probando varias opciones y en todas me arroja el mismo error...

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22\bin>java -jar c:/weblogic_fuentes/fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar

Error: Unable to access jarfile c:/weblogic_fuentes/fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22\bin>java -jar "c:/weblogic_fuentes/fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar"

Error: Unable to access jarfile c:/weblogic_fuentes/fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22\bin>java -jar "c:\weblogic_fuentes\fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar"

Error: Unable to access jarfile c:\weblogic_fuentes\fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22\bin>java -jar c:\weblogic_fuentes\fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar

Error: Unable to access jarfile c:\weblogic_fuentes\fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar

Comment: Has probado a lanzarlo desde la raiz del archivo jar?: `java -jar fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar`

Comment: Sí también lo hice y me arroja el mismo error...                                                         C:\weblogic_fuentes\fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls>java -jar fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar

Comment: Prueba a mover el archivo jar de carpeta, por ejemplo al escritorio y vuelva a ejecutar el comando `java -jar fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar` Puede ser tema de permisos

Comment: Hola, nada aún, lo cambié al escritorio y persiste el mismo error...

Comment: Me di cuenta que el archivo tenía extensión jar.jar y lo ejecuté y sí intentó instalar el weblogic pero me arrojó otro error...                                                                    Los logs están aquí: C:\Users\mjcd1\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2024-03-25_05-46-21PM.